# Database lose Foreign key, Auto Inc, Indexes on import on cpanel phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

i just completed a system and in the process of moving from localhost to an online host i noticed that all indexes,  auto increment columns,  foreign and primary keys , literally every relation disappear..     The user of the db has all priviledges.

I thought maybe it was an error while exporting from localhost phpmyadmin,  but then,  i. created a test db on my pc running xampp,, and i imported the same db (the one misbehaving on online phpmyadmin) to the test db..

Voila.. Its normal in the test db.. All relationship and indexes are intact.. So am really Confused  as i really need the relationship to work.. I cascaded deletes for FK and a whole lot of stuff depends on the relationships
Thanks in advance

**Edited:**   
See part of the sql file    for one table,   and i have about 40 tables     ..

### -- Table structure for table `chat`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `chat` (
```

`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id_one` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id_two` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(25) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

```
--
-- Dumping data for table `chat`
--

INSERT INTO `chat` (`id`, `user_id_one`, `user_id_two`, `date`) VALUES
(2, 3, 2, '25-06-18 11:57:12');
```

---

### --     Indexes for table `chat`

```
   ALTER TABLE `chat`
   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD KEY `user_id_one` (`user_id_one`), ADD KEY 
  `user_id_two` (`user_id_two`);
```

### -- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `chat`

```
ALTER TABLE `chat`
MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=3;
```

### -- Constraints for table `chat`

```
 ALTER TABLE `chat`
ADD CONSTRAINT `ch_uid` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id_one`) REFERENCES `account` 
(`user_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE,
ADD CONSTRAINT `ch_uid2` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id_two`) REFERENCES `account` 
(`user_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: Are you specifying `ENGINE=InnoDB` for each table? The other common storage engine, MyISAM, does not support foreign keys. If you create a MyISAM table with FK definitions, it will accept the syntax but silently ignores the FK's (i.e. not create them). If InnoDB isn't the default storage engine on the MySQL server you deploy to, you will have to specify it at the end of each CREATE TABLE statement.

Comment: All my tablea are InnoDB,  from what i see on phpmyadmin when i click my db

Comment: Bill's point was to check your dump if it specified the table type.

Comment: look at the what i edited in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.. 
The issue was with my hosting providers. 
The production phpmyadmin they have  did not support any previous version of mysql dump ..and my the version of phpmyadmin i used on my pc is not the same as theirs on cpanel... 
So i had to download the latest version of xampp,
 export all my databases,
  uninstall the previous version..
install the latest version,
create my db again,,
import my sql dump file,
 all my indexes were intact.. 
Then export the db again,,
I imported the new db to my cpanel phpmyadmin and poof... Its ok.

Seems like the way the older version compiled the dump file is not the same as they compile in the latest version.. 
And only an offline version of phpmyadmin can recompile a dump file of an older version of phpmyadmin

Not really genius but it saved me,, and no other solution from other questions ,blogs and research worked.. 
I hope this helps someone someday.